# javascript recursive function memory leak

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory

I am not good at English. Successfully make recursive call function. However, there is a memory leak for some reason. The question is that there is no return. The purpose of this feature is to view and explore objects, arrays, and the rest of their properties.
How do I change the code if I have a problem with my return?
Thank you in advance.

I was able to know the cause of the memory leak through Google dev tools profiles.

```js
function recursionProperty(prop, obj, fn) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(item => recursionProperty('files', item, fn));
  } else if (obj instanceof Object) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop => {
      const value = obj[prop];
      recursionProperty(prop, value, fn);
    });
  } else {
    fn(prop, obj);
  }
}

recursionProperty(null, {foo:'bar', baz: ['x','y']}, (prop, obj) => console.log(prop, obj));
```

my original code

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import errors from '@feathersjs/errors';

import connections from '../../../connections';
import config from '../../../config';

/**
 * @param req
 * @param serviceItem
 * @param query
 * @returns {Promise<any>}
 */
const getServicePromise = async (req, serviceItem, query) => {
  let serviceName = serviceItem;
  if (typeof serviceItem !== 'string') {
    serviceName = `datasets/${serviceItem.name}`;
  }

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let result;
    let objResult;
    try {
      result = await req.app.service(serviceName).find(query);
    } catch (e) {
      result = null;
      console.log(e);
    }
    // console.log(result);
    if (result) {
      if (typeof serviceItem !== 'string') {
         objResult = { [serviceItem.name]: result.data };
      } else {
         objResult = { [serviceName]: result.data };
      }
      resolve(objResult);
    } if (result === null) {
      objResult = { [serviceName]: [] };
      resolve(objResult);
    } else {
      reject({
        error: 'Not found data.'
      });
    }
  });
};

/**
 * 파일 경로 프로퍼티를 찾는 재귀함수
 * 객체, 배열, 원시타입 등 여러 타입이 섞여있어도 사용 가능
 * @param prop
 * @param obj
 * @param fn
 */
function recursionProperty(prop, obj, fn) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(item => recursionProperty('files', item, fn));
  } else if (obj instanceof Object) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop => {
      const value = obj[prop];
      recursionProperty(prop, value, fn);
    });
  } else {
    fn(prop, obj);
  }
}

/**
 * @param req
 * @returns {Promise<{any}>}
 */
const getService = async req => {
  const result = {};
  const serverPath = [];
  const { sheet, dataset, icon } = req.data;
  const iconState = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(req.data, 'icon');
  const sheetState = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(req.data, 'sheet');
  const datasetState = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(req.data, 'dataset');

  try {
    // sheets
    if (sheetState) {
      const itemList = ['sheets'];
      if (sheet.length === 0) {
        const query = {
          query: {
          },
        };
        await Promise.all(itemList.map(serviceItem => getServicePromise(req, serviceItem, query))).then(data => {
            data.forEach(item => {
              Object.assign(result, item);
            });
        });
      } else if (sheet.length > 0) {
        const query = {
          query: {
            _id: {
              $in: sheet,
            },
          },
        };
        await Promise.all(itemList.map(serviceItem => getServicePromise(req, serviceItem, query))).then(data => {
          data.forEach(item => {
            Object.assign(result, item);
          });
        });
      } else {
        result.sheets = [];
      }
    } else {
      result.sheets = [];
    }


    // 파일 경로 구하기
    if (sheet) {
      const { sheets } = result;
      // const filePath = [];

      recursionProperty('files', sheets, (prop, value) => {
        // 여기서 원하는 필드인지 검색후 처리함
        if (prop === 'fullPath' && fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../../../files', value))) {
          // filePath.push(path.join(__dirname, '../../../../files', value));
          serverPath.push(value);
        }
      });

      // const deduplication = Array.from(new Set(serverPath));
      // const deduplicationPath = await deduplicationFilePath(deduplication);
      //
      // Object.assign(result, { filePath: deduplicationPath });
    } else {
      // result.filePath = [];
    }

    // files
    if (sheet) {
      const deduplicationFiles = Array.from(new Set(serverPath));
      if (deduplicationFiles.length > 0) {
        const query = {
          query: {
            $sort: {
              createdAt: -1,
            },
            fullPath: {
              $in: deduplicationFiles,
            },
          }
        };
        const files = await req.app.service('files').find(query);
        Object.assign(result, { files: files.data });
      } else {
        result.files = [];
      }
    } else {
      result.files = [];
    }

    // dataset
    if (datasetState) {
      const query = {
        query: {
          // $limit: 100000
        }
      };

      if (dataset.length === 0) {
        const meta = await req.app.service('datasets/_meta_').find();
        Object.assign(result, { _meta_: meta });
        const db = await connections.getConnection(connections.DATASETS_DB);
        const collectionNames = _.filter(await db.client.db(config.database_datasets.dbname).listCollections().toArray(), o => o.name !== '_meta_');

        // collectionNames.forEach(str => {
        //   const detectA = iconvDetect.detect(Buffer.from(str.name));
        //   console.log('collection type', str.name, detectA);
        // });

        await Promise.all(meta.map(serviceItem => {
          // const detectA = iconvDetect.detect(Buffer.from(serviceItem.key));
          // console.log('meta type', serviceItem.key, detectA);
          return getServicePromise(req, `datasets/${serviceItem.key}`, query);
        })).then(data => {
          Object.assign(result, { datasets: data });
        });
      } else if (dataset.length > 0) {
        const metaQuery = {
          query: {
            $sort: {
              createdAt: -1,
            },
            key: {
              $in: dataset
            }
          }
        };
        const meta = await req.app.service('datasets/_meta_').find(metaQuery);
        // console.log(meta);
        Object.assign(result, { _meta_: meta });
        await Promise.all(dataset.map(serviceItem => getServicePromise(req, `datasets/${serviceItem}`, query))).then(data => {
          const d = Array.from(new Set(data));
          const s = d.filter(item => item !== null);
          if (d.length > 0) {
            Object.assign(result, { datasets: s });
          } else {
            result.datasets = [];
            result._meta_ = [];
          }
        });
      } else {
        result.datasets = [];
        result._meta_ = [];
      }
    } else {
      result.datasets = [];
      result._meta_ = [];
    }

    if (iconState) {
      const itemList = ['iconCategories', 'iconItems'];
      const query = {};

      if (icon.length === 0) {
        await Promise.all(itemList.map(serviceItem => getServicePromise(req, serviceItem, query))).then(data => {
          data.forEach(item => {
            Object.assign(result, item);
          });
        });
      }
    } else {
      result.iconCategories = [];
      result.iconItems = [];
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw new errors.BadRequest('The data is invalid.', e);
  }
  return result;
};

export default getService;
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"memory leak"_? _"How do I change the code if I have a problem with my return?"_ What problem do you have?

Comment: Have just converted the code to snippet which runs the function. This function does not return anything but lets you have a callback. As @ThomasSablik already mentioned, what is the issue here?

Comment: @Aivaras If I run my original code, there is a memory leak. When I commented on the code I had just uploaded there, the memory leak disappeared. So the cause is suspected as a recursive function.

Comment: What is `original code`, how did you determine `memory leak`, what arguments did you use when calling the function?

Comment: @Aivaras Arguments are objects in array type and contain objects of different types. Contains all types you know. And I added what you asked. to my question

Comment: You are using `fs.existsSync` in that loop, for every property found it does a blocking operation.

Comment: @Aivaras Thank you. What you said and `serverPath.push(value);` were the reasons. But can memory leak be caused by push?

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely no memory leak in your code. Yes, recursive functions can be more memory aggressive than normal functions, because the call stack can grow very quickly, but remember that all functions will implicitly return even if there is no `return` statement. (Imagine that there is always a `return undefined;` line at the end of all your functions)

When doing a recursion, call stack will grow until you reach the bottom of a recursion branch (no function returns until then). Once the recursion branch end is reached, in your case this happens anytime you reach your `else` block, call stack will 'collapse' and all functions preceding will 'return'.

Memory will ultimately be freed by garbage collection as required.